# Chrome PDF Downloads Cached File

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf

We have a web app that displays a PDF in an iframe. When using the Chrome PDF viewer's built-in download it seems to be downloading a cached PDF, not the currently displayed PDF. If we use the print option however, and then choose print to PDF, it downloads the proper PDF file. After searching around I've come across a few odd solutions involving HTTP headers, but nothing so far has fixed the issue. Additionally, if I open the url for the iframe content as its own tab and then download, it downloads the correct PDF file.

Comment: I think you should see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Does this only happen in Google Chrome? If not, I think you should remove that tag.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón it does indeed only happen in Chrome, Firefox and Edge work just fine.

Comment: Yep having the exact same problem here ! Only happening in Chrome !

Comment: We are also facing the same issue. The preview in iframe shows the proper PDF but when we try to download the same , It displays the old version. The issue is very specific to the latest chrome version 88

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this happens at least in Chrome and Edge browsers.

It happens because the pdf file that you pass to the viewer (iframe or PDFObject) is always cached internally with the same name.
**You can solve it add a random number or date and time** as the name of the pdf.

I give you an example of how I solved it:

xhtml file:

```
<iframe type="application/pdf" id="idReport" src="#{yourController.serverAndContextPath}/PDFServlet" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

or

```
<object type="application/pdf" id="idReport" data="#{yourController.serverAndContextPath}/PDFServlet" width="100%" height="500px"/>
```

Servlet class:

```
public class PDFServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                     
             Date date = new Date();
             DateFormat hourdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");   
             response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf"); 
             response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + "pdfFileName" + hourdateFormat.format(date) + ".pdf" + "\"");
                                     
    }
    
}
```